# Superset useage an/or log in through docker

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I have tried to install the Apache Superset tool as directed in the official documentation, but have encountered all sorts of problems.

I decided to go instead through a `docker pull` and pulled the **amancevice/superset** image from the **Docker Hub** and all went well, but now when I start the container and get the Superset landing page it asks me to log in and I don't see any way to know what is the password for the **Admin** user or the **superset** user or any other user. Nor I see any way to create a user and password in the containers itself.

Answer (score 1):

1) Find docker image using docker images

2) Go inside docker image using commands:
docker exec -it  bash

3) Inside docker image run the superset-init file.
Then try with admin/admin as superset will load default roles,permissions and dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

When the docker image is running open the docker console and then run

```
fabmanager create-admin --app superset
```

Comment: This is what I get: PS C:\Windows\system32> fabmanager create-admin --app superset
fabmanager : The term 'fabmanager' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ fabmanager create-admin --app superset
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fabmanager:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

You are missing execution of `superset-init` to setup the credentials.

You might like to try below steps:

```
# pull docker image
docker pull amancevice/superset

# setup configuration directory
mkdir -p ~/superset/conf & mkdir -p ~/superset/data

# run image (user `0` is root user)
docker run --name superset -u 0 -d -p 8088:8088 -v ~/superset/conf:/etc/superset -v ~/superset/data:/var/lib/superset amancevice/superset

# setup credentials (such as admin/admin)
docker exec -it superset superset-init
```

Then, access the service at http://localhost:8088/

```
# load examples
docker exec -it superset superset load_examples
```